# Can anyone warn a man's wife to give her the status of a sotah?

Tags: halacha, beit-din-court, ketubah, sotah-secluded-woman

In the Mishna, [Sotah 4:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sotah.4.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (and Bavli 27a) it explains that in certain situations Beit Din may warn a woman not to be secluded with a man and this warning carries the legal status of *kinuy* such that if she is secluded with the same man later on she may lose her ketubah. I recall learning, but cannot find, a Sifre which extends this ability to warn to 'neighbors' as well.

I would like to know if there is any halachic discussion as to what the status would be if any person, besides Beit Din and neighbors, warn a married woman about seclusion (in a case where the husband cannot, such as if he is in jail). Are other people also able to trigger *kinuy* such that she can potentially lose her ketubah, or is it only the Beit Din and 'neighbors'?

Comment: "trigger kinuy such that she can potentially lose her ketubah" that could be very different from triggering kinuy such that she would undergo the full sotah ritual, for the record

Comment: There is a gemara addressing the wife of a blind man that the Bet din intervened

Comment: @DanF if a woman commits adultery, she is forever forbidden to have sex with her husband or her adulterer (and they with her). Doesn't matter if they get caught or not or if she drinks Sotah water or not.

Comment: @DoubleAA I only remember sources, that the males are forbidden, what is the source that the prohibition is also on her? (I understand that it might be lifnai iver, but is more than that?)